# "Hosted network couldn't be started" when I try to run "netsh wlan start hostednetwork"

Tags: windows, wireless-networking

When I try to run `netsh wlan start hostednetwork`, I get the following message:

> The hosted network couldn't be started. A device attached to the system is not
>   functioning.

What should I do?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?  Did you actually setup a hosted network?  What exact steps did you take in setting it up?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18431634/netsh-wlan-start-hostednetwork-command-not-working-no-matter-what-i-try

Answer (score 0):

Try the following three ways to see whether any of them helps:

1. Device Manager --> Network Adapter. On the menu, click View-->Show hidden devices, and see whether you can find the one (in Network Adapter) for hosted network. If yes, right click it and select "Enable" to enable it.
2. If it doesn't work, reinstall the wifi driver. Right click the wireless device in Network adapter and uninstall it. Then scan for hardware changes to re-install it automatically. See whether the hosted network can be started or not.
3. Otherwise, right click the wifi device in Network Adapter, and select Properties. In the Power Management tab, tick "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power".

Answer (score 0):

After i tried all the solutions given above and it proved abortive, i further on with my research to solve the problem which was later solved. What was mistaking is that, my wifi switch (on & off switch) was off, well not all system has switch. But turning on my wifi solved the problem